# How to skip image-based pages in camelot?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tabula, python-camelot

I'm running a for loop for multiple pdfs with multiple pages to extract multiple tables. Problem is when I run the for loop for multiple pdfs if there are any pdfs that contain image-based format at page 1 or 2 and tables start from page 2 or 3 respectively, for loop stops and following error is displayed.

```
\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\camelot\parsers\lattice.py:411: UserWarning: page-1 is image-based, camelot only works on text-based pages.

\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\camelot\parsers\lattice.py:411: UserWarning: page-2 is image-based, camelot only works on text-based pages.
```

I want a solution where I can skip any image based page and continue the loop for the next page.